# iPhone iOS 10 and Linux - replacement for Music, etc

Tags: linux, media-player, iphone-app

Just got an iPhone upgrade, but now I am stuck on something.  My old iPhone 4 I had an app called "Files" that allowed me to upload files via web browser or enter a URL for a file and it would fetch it.  It had a built-in media player, PDF viewer, etc.

Checking the App Store, the app isn't available any more from the same publisher.  So now I need a replacement.

Requirements:

- Upload media files via wireless OR via plugging in to my Linux systems via USB.  I do not have a Mac or Windows machine of any type available to me.
- Able to add files to the Music app that comes with iOS OR have its own media player built in.
- Support for play lists, random/shuffle/repeat play required.
- MP3 support required, movie file (mp4/mov) support would be nice but not required, PDF or other document file support would be nice but not required.

Prefer free, but low one-time cost is acceptable.  No adverts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.  Finally found something called oplayer .  Hits all my points, free ad based version or $3 to buy.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Play Music](https://play.google.com/music) is the best option for you.
Can upload your favorites tracks through your browser and listen on your smartphone, tablet or TV.

Comment: If I wanted to use up my bandwidth I'd drop the files on my own media server :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

[VLC mobile](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/vlc-for-mobile/id650377962?mt=8) has a built in http server. Once you enable it it shows you an IP/port, once you visit that address from your computer browser you can upload files.